# onStart on MvxFormsApplication never called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am developing an application with **MvvmCross 5.1.1** and **MvvmCross.Forms 5.1.1**

I have a CoreApp in my PCL project where I start the services:

```
public class CoreApp : MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication
    {


        void prepareRestServices() {

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpLoggingHandler())
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(SharedConfig.BASE_API_URL),
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SharedConfig.TIMEOUT_OPERATION_MINUTES)
            };

            // Register REST services
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IAuthenticationRestService>(() => RestServiceFactory.getService<IAuthenticationRestService>(httpClient));
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IParentsRestService>(() => RestServiceFactory.getService<IParentsRestService>(httpClient));
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IChildrenRestService>(() => RestServiceFactory.getService<IChildrenRestService>(httpClient));
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IDeviceGroupsRestService>(() => RestServiceFactory.getService<IDeviceGroupsRestService>(httpClient));
        }

        void prepareMappers() {

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<ParentDTO, ParentEntity>();
                cfg.CreateMap<SonDTO, SonEntity>();
                cfg.CreateMap<DeviceDTO, DeviceEntity>();
            });
        }



        public override void Initialize()
        {


            prepareRestServices();

            prepareMappers();

            CreatableTypes()
                .InNamespace("Bullytect.Core.Services")
                .EndingWith("ServiceImpl")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();


            Mvx.RegisterType<IValidator, Validator>();

            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);

            RegisterAppStart(new CustomAppStart());

        }

    }
```

And another App class that inherits from MvxFormsApplication to configure the I18N and register by application events and FCM notifications.

```
public partial class App : MvxFormsApplication
    {

        private void ConfigLocale()
        {
            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS || Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
            {
                var ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
                AppResources.Culture = ci; // set the RESX for resource localization
                DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().SetLocale(ci); // set the Thread for locale-aware methods
            }
        }

        public App()
        {
            ConfigLocale();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void OnAuthenticatedUserMessage(AuthenticatedUserMessage authenticatedUserMessage)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("OnAuthenticatedUserMessage ...");

            var deviceGroupsService = Mvx.Resolve<IDeviceGroupsService>();
            // save token
            deviceGroupsService.saveDevice(CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id, Settings.FcmToken).Subscribe(device => {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Device Saved: {0}", device.ToString()));
            });

        }


        void OnExceptionOcurredMessage(ExceptionOcurredMessage exceptionOcurredMessage) 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnExceptionOcurredMessage ...");

            var userDialogs = Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>();

            userDialogs.ShowError(AppResources.Global_ErrorOcurred);

            if (exceptionOcurredMessage.Ex != null)
                exceptionOcurredMessage.Ex.Track();

        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Forms App OnStart ...");

            var messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
            // subscribe to Authenticated User Message
            messenger.Subscribe<AuthenticatedUserMessage>(OnAuthenticatedUserMessage);
            // subscribe to Exception Ocurred Message
            messenger.Subscribe<ExceptionOcurredMessage>(OnExceptionOcurredMessage);

            //Handling FCM Token
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN REC: {p.Token}");
                Settings.FcmToken = p.Token;
            };
            Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN: {CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Token}");
            Settings.FcmToken = CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Token;

        }
    }
```

The problem is that the **onStart method is never called**, and I have no other place to initialize those components.

Then I also put the code of my **MvxFormsApplicationDelegate** and the **MvxFormsIosSetup**.

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : MvxFormsApplicationDelegate
    {

        public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            var setup = new Setup(this, Window);
            setup.Initialize();

            var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
            startup.Start();

            XFGloss.iOS.Library.Init();

            LoadApplication(setup.FormsApplication);

            Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);

            return true;
        }


        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            #if DEBUG
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken, FirebaseTokenType.Sandbox);
            #endif
            #if RELEASE
                                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken,FirebaseTokenType.Production);
            #endif

        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

        }

        // To receive notifications in foregroung on iOS 9 and below.
        // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
            // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

            // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method. 
            // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
            // automatically with method swizzling enabled.
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Do your magic to handle the notification data
            System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
        }

        public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Connect();
            base.OnActivated(uiApplication);

        }
        public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
        {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers and store the application state.
            // If your application supports background exection this method is called instead of WillTerminate when the user quits.
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

**MvvmFormsIOSSetup**

```
public class Setup : MvxFormsIosSetup
    {
        public Setup(IMvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
            : base(applicationDelegate, window)
        {
        }

        protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
        {
            return new CoreApp();
        }
        protected override MvvmCross.Forms.Core.MvxFormsApplication CreateFormsApplication()
        {
            return new App();
        }

        protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
        {
            return new DebugTrace();
        }


        protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
        {
            return new CustomPresenter(Window, FormsApplication);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this method is not called ?. I have something wrong in my configuration?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did the screen show nothing?

Comment: the application works correctly, the only thing is that the onStart code does not run.

Comment: Was the `App` class initialized? Were all the methods in `App` not triggered or just the onStart? You may add somes breakpoints to check.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have checked it and no life cycle method is called.

Comment: Could you provide a sample project to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Or you may try to use the full namespace of the App() in `MvvmCross.Forms.Core.MvxFormsApplication CreateFormsApplication()` to have a try.

Comment: I already have it, the project I have here https://github.com/sergio11/bullytect-xamarin